# Can I use .vscode/lauch.json in Android Studio for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

My new team is mostly using VSCode, whereas I prefer Android Studio. I would like to keep using Android Studio, I just need to figure out how. Basically we have a dozen or so apps all defined in the launch.json via different remote_configs. I obviously cannot share the launch configs but here is a sample:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "app_1",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "preLaunchTask": "prebuild_setup",
      "args": [
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "app_2",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "preLaunchTask": "prebuild_setup",
      "args": [

      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

It is just too many to create an main_app_n.dart for every app, so how could I do this? Is there a way to do this? Or am I doomed to use VSCode (;